# Laravel query builder raw AND statement

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need to run a raw SQL query part in Laravel.

The raw SQL would look basically like this:

```
AND (forretningsadresse_fylke = 'HEDMARK' 
    AND (forretningsadresse_kommune = 'HAMAR') 
    OR (forretningsadresse_kommune = 'ELVERUM')
) 
OR (forretningsadresse_fylke = 'HORDALAND' 
    AND (forretningsadresse_kommune = 'BERGEN')
)
```

I try to use:

```
$result = Company::where(function($a) use($input, $sql) {

        // Name or keywords LIKE string
        $a -> where('navn', 'LIKE', '%'. $input['query_string'] .'%');
        $a -> where('keywords', 'LIKE', '%'. $input['query_string'] .'%');
        if (!empty($sql)) {
            $a -> where(DB::statement($sql));
        }

    });

    $result = $result -> take($input['limit'])       // Take $limit
                      -> offset($input['offset'])    // Offset by $offset
                      -> orderBy('rank', 'DESC')     // Sponsors first
                      -> get();
```

But it doesn't work. See the error below.
How would I get this to work? Thanks in advance!

QueryException in Connection.php line 673: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND (forretningsadresse_fylke = 'AKERSHUS')' at line 1 (SQL: AND (forretningsadresse_fylke = 'AKERSHUS') )

EDIT: The table has 1 million rows, and I use this method to create the raw query: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0r79.png

Comment: Can you please write the query in full

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues with your code:

1. You are using `DB::statement` where you should be using `DB::raw`. `DB::statement` will execute the string that you pass as an argument and that is not what you need. You need to pass a raw statement to be included to the query builder.
2. Assuming the raw block you posted is the `$sql` parameter, then you need to remove the starting `AND`, otherwise the query will end up with `.... and AND (`, which will throw an error.

Given this, you need to update your code to:

```
// Notice the removal of the `AND`
$sql = "(forretningsadresse_fylke = 'HEDMARK' 
        AND (forretningsadresse_kommune = 'HAMAR') 
        OR (forretningsadresse_kommune = 'ELVERUM')
    ) 
    OR (forretningsadresse_fylke = 'HORDALAND' 
        AND (forretningsadresse_kommune = 'BERGEN')
    )";

$result = Company::where(function($a) use($input, $sql) {
    // Name or keywords LIKE string
    $a->where('navn', 'LIKE', '%'. $input['query_string'] .'%');
    $a->where('keywords', 'LIKE', '%'. $input['query_string'] .'%');
    if (!empty($sql)) {
        // Using DB::raw instead of DB::statement
        $a->where(DB::raw($sql));
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but it maxed the execution time of 30 seconds, wich is quiet much. The table has 1 million rows, and 20 colums. Is there any way I could optimize the database besides adding indexes? Or optimizing the query? But thank you though.

Comment: @Kaizokupuffball, now that's another issue. Your best bet is to apply indexes to `forretningsadresse_fylke`, `forretningsadresse_kommune`, `navn` and `keywords`. However, since you have LIKES, that statement will take a long time to execute. Best bet is to take the select statement and prepend it with "explain". Something like `explain select *  from ....` to profile the query. If you're unable to fix that issue, you should probably add a new question on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$result = Company::where('navn', 'LIKE', '%'. $input['query_string'] .'%')
    ->where('keywords', 'LIKE', '%'. $input['query_string'] .'%')
    ->where(function($query){
        $query->where('forretningsadresse_fylke', '=', 'HEDMARK' )
              ->where('forretningsadresse_kommune', '=', 'HAMAR')
              ->orWhere('forretningsadresse_kommune','=', 'ELVERUM');
    })
    ->where(function($query){
        $query->orWhere('forretningsadresse_fylke','=', 'HORDALAND')
              ->where('forretningsadresse_kommune', '=', 'BERGEN');
   })
   ->take($input['limit'])       // Take $limit
   ->offset($input['offset'])    // Offset by $offset
   ->orderBy('rank', 'DESC')     // Sponsors first
   ->get();
```

hope it helps

Comment: I don't think I could do this approach.
I create the raw sql this way: http://i.imgur.com/Q5SRP58.png
I try to find a way to this simpler, but I can't figure out how to do this.